# Azure intro questions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I just started learning Azure and have some dumb questions. Feeling lost.
If you could guys help, I would be eternal grateful!

1. Suppose I have created my ASP.NET Core MVC application. How to import some Azure functions to it? Do I create additional project in my solution and add reference to it? Or is there another way to do it?
2. Do I need to have published my whole MVC app into Azure in order to use the Azure functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The MVC app and the Function app are two different applications. You do not need one to have the other.
   If your solution contains a MVC app, that's fine. You can add different projects for each function, so each function will have its own project inside the solution.
   The project type for the function is class library, but it will be easier if you just use the template Azure Functions (requires the Azure Development module to be installed in Visual Studio).
2. You only need to publish the function project.

Comment: So, I added Azure Functions as separate project in my MVC solution. My question is: how can I use this Azure Function in my controller? Can I bind Azure Queue Trigger Function with IActionResult in the controller?
I am building Images Upload project, and want for button click event to have message in the queue. How to build that?

Comment: Maybe you can check this learning module about serverless applications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/create-serverless-applications/ 
I think it should provide all the information you need. If you still have questions afterwards, just post them on stackoverflow.